# Can I get credentials by AWS IAM Role published by another aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts

Unfortunately, I lost serveral days for this work.

How can I get temporary credentials by IAM Role? Is this possible?

here is my scenario and code.(AWS SDK on java)

- STS instance by AWS account accessKey and secretKey

  ```
  AWSSecurityTokenService tokenService = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsProperty.getAccess(), awsProperty.getSecret()));
  ```
- make AssumeRoleRequest

  ```
  AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest();
  assumeRoleRequest.setRoleArn(arn);
  assumeRoleRequest.setDurationSeconds(900);
  assumeRoleRequest.setRoleSessionName("for_test");
  assumeRoleRequest.setExternalId("ext_id");
  ```
- get SessionCredentials

  ```
  AssumeRoleResult roleResult =  tokenService.assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);
  Credentials credentials = roleResult.getCredentials();

  AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(credentials.getAccessKeyId(), credentials.getSecretAccessKey(), credentials.getSessionToken());
  ```
- work

  ```
  AmazonCloudFrontClient cloudFrontClient = new AmazonCloudFrontClient(awsCredentials);
  ```

It throws `AWSSecurityTokenServiceException`

```
User: arn:aws:iam::{account}:user/{user_name} is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::{role_account}:role/{role_name} (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

I make policy like this. attach to both of IAM Role and IAM User.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1490674259000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:

I tested policy(modified) with IAM Policy Simulator.
select `AWS Security Token Service-AssumeRole` with `IAM Role ARN` - it allowed.

Comment: Are you assuming a role in a different AWS Account? Does your role have a [trust relationship](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_modify.html) defined?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you so much! I confirm trust relationship and fix parameter. it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a [trust relationship](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_modify.html) to your IAM Role to permit it to be assumed.